# Prove that if $a_0\geq 2$, $f(n)$ is not prime for some integer $z$.

Tags: number-theory

Let $f(x) = a_kx^k + a_{k-1}x^{k-1} + \cdots + a_0$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients where $a_k \neq 0$. Prove that if $a_0 \geq 2$, $f(n)$ is not prime for some integer $z$.

I know I will eventually have to show that a polynomial of degree $k-1$ with real coefficients has at most $k-1$ real roots, but I have not had much luck thus far with induction.

Comment: Have you tried the Rational Root thm :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem  ?

Comment: What if $k=0$ and $a_0$ is prime?  (I.e., there's a tacit assumption that the polynomial is nonconstant.)

Comment: The MathJax style here was bizarre and I've cleaned it up.

Comment: Please do not deface your questions.

Comment: This was asked and answered per question itself.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $\ $ If not $\,f(n)\,$ is prime for all $\,n\,$ so $\,a_0 = f(0)= p\,$ is prime. $\,f(pn)\,$ is prime for all $\,n,\,$ and $\,p\mid f(pn),\,$ so $\,f(pn) = p.\,$ So $\,f(px)-p\,$ has infinitely many roots so $\,f(px) = p,\,$ so $\,f(x)=p.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Plug in $x = Na_0$ into the polynomial where $N$ is a large integer and see what you get. Note the leading term will dominate.